# VBScript Opening CSV and splitting

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I have made a script that allows the user to open a file using the shell browser and once selected they are prompted to enter the interval in which they want to split the .CSV file down into smaller files.

The problem that arises is that once I select the file using the browser I get an unspecified error with the code 80004005 it appears on line 15 character 1 and I have no idea how to solve this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim objFSO, objInputFile, objOutputFile
Dim intLine, intFile
Dim strHeaders
Dim strInputFile, strOutputPrefix, strLine
Dim MyDate

Dim shell 
Dim file 
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")    
Set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a file:", &H4000)    
BrowseForFile = file.self.Path 

strInputFile = BrowseForFile
strOutputPrefix = objFSO.GetBaseName(strInputFile) & DatePart("yyyy", Now) & "-" & DatePart("m", Now) & "-" & DatePart("d", Now) 
userSplit = InputBox("Enter when you want to split")

intFile = 1
intLine = 0

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFile, ForReading)

If (objInputFile.AtEndOfStream = True) Then
  ' The file is empty
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

strHeaders = objInputFile.ReadLine

Do While (objInputFile.AtEndOfStream = False)


  strLine = objInputFile.ReadLine

  If (intLine <= 0) Then
    Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strOutputPrefix & "_" & intFile & ".csv", True)
    objOutputFile.WriteLine strHeaders

    intLine = 1
  End If

  objOutputFile.WriteLine strLine

  If (intLine >= userSplit) Then
    objOutputFile.Close
    Set objOutputFile = Nothing

    intFile = intFile + 1
    intLine = 0
  Else
    intLine = intLine + 1
  End If
Loop
```

Comment: You have `Option Explicit On` ;) You have to declare `BrowseForFile`. Also what is `objFSO`? You have to create the object to use it. I haven't checked the rest of the code after that

Comment: Still throwing an error on "Set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a file:", &H4000)"

Comment: It is working for me. You are doing this for VBScript? Tested on Win 7, 64 bit

Comment: yes im just editing in notepad on windows 7 64bit, when It runs up until i select the file

Answer (score 0):

Your BrowseForFolder call misses the third/option parameter; so change

```
Set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a file:", &H4000)
```

to

```
Set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a file:", 0, &H4000)
```

**The above (kept for context for comments) is all wrong**

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) state clearly:

> Creates a dialog box that enables the user to select a folder and then
>   returns the selected folder's Folder object.

so you can **display** the files, but not pick/return them.

Comment: If I change to this it doesn't let me select a file, just a folder :(

Comment: Can you get past the selecting of the file Siddharth?

Comment: Yes I can only if I select an xls file and not a csv file.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner How do I go about opening a file then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35074/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-nathan-hawthorne)